# What is the relation between spark parallelism and Elasticseach scroll slice?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

We are noticing that there is some relation between the Spark parallelism `spark.default.parallelism` and `es.scroll.size` but I am not understanding it properly.

In one case I tried to launch a spark job with parallelism set to 8000 and I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) (172.30.91.153 executor 15): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: illegal_argument_exception: The number of slices [2666] is too large. It must be less than [1024]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_slices_per_scroll] index level setting.
{"slice":{"id":1138,"max":2666},"query":{"match_all":{}}}
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:477)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:311)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsBytes(MemoryStore.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1440)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I changed the parallelism to 4000, it says `The number of slices [1333] is too large`

I don't seem to find any proper answer. I am using 9 ES Pods each having a shard. And 150 executors for the job.

Comment: Per the documentation - number of slices is calculated by this `es.input.max.docs.per.partition`  -

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_input

Comment: @Nirmal we have not set this parameter, the documentation says ```By default, this value is unset, and the input partitions are calculated based on the number of shards in the indices being read```, we are using 9 ES pods each with a shard. Also does the ```spark.default.parallelism``` and ```slice``` similar thing?